# Meteor & locks in publication

Tags: javascript, meteor

Scenario: I want to display an item to the user, then lock it, so that no one else can see it, and once the user is done with it, display the next item.

The problem is that the query in the publication has to check for the lock. So as soon as you change the lock, the cursor updates and the item changes.

How could this be solved?

**Edit:**
Sample code in publication, which would not work:

```
var item = Items.find({
    locked: false
}, {
    limit: 1
});

var itemObj = item.fetch()[0];
Items.update(itemObj._id, {$set: {locked: true}});
return item;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be a better solution is to assign an item to a userId. Once he is finished with the item then the item is unassigned again.

That could be done like this:

- Method call `Items.assignToUser` - looks for an item to be assigned and sets `assignedUserId`
- Subscribe to all items assigned to me (maybe limit to 1)

When finished:
Method call `Items.unassignFromUser` - sets the field `assignedUserId` to `null` again.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to first query the database, update it, then send the cursor on the document:

```
Meteor.publish('somePub', function() {
  var itemId = Items.findOne({locked : false})._id;

  Items.update(itemId, {$set: {locked: true}});

  return Items.find(itemId);
});
```

Step-by-step:

- [`findOne`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone) returns a document, not a cursor. No need to `fetch()[0]` then. We only need its `_id`;
- The update is the same as yours;
- We [send the cursor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find), aiming for a single document because we provided an ID as parameter.

Note that you will need to stop the subscription and re-run it each time you want to select a new item. If you do that with template subscriptions, you could simply reload the template, causing the subscription to be stopped then re-ran (for example, by clicking a "Next" button).